# SQL join not recognising join

Tags: php, sql

Below is my database structure:

```
assignments(assignment_id, year, semester, title, number, weighting, handout, handin, feedback, wordcount, briefd, profile_image, sub_details, add_note, author, user_id, module_id)

requests(request_id, assignment_id, allow, requestee)
```

I thought this would be a simple task, I want to get a count of the people from assignments.user_id who have requests in the request table. I have tried the following but I'm getting SQL errors:

```
SELECT COUNT(allow) FROM requests WHERE requests.assignment_id = assignments.user_id = 31
```

Error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'assignments.user_id' in 'where clause'
```

Perhaps I need a join? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You never reference the assignments table in your SQL, as @mihal says, a JOIN is the best way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(allow) 
FROM requests WHERE requests.assignment_id = assignments.user_id AND
assignments.user_id=31
```

But better use explicit JOINs

```
SELECT count(assignments.user_id) FROM assignments 
JOIN requests ON requests.assignment_id = assignments.assignment_id
WHERE assignments.user_id=31
```

Comment: Perfect, does exactly what I want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(assignments.user_id) 
FROM assignments 
JOIN requests ON requests.assignment_id = assignments.assignment_id 
WHERE assignments.user_id = 31
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use on for joining 2 tables not Where

```
SELECT COUNT(allow) FROM requests ON requests.assignment_id = assignments.user_id 
         WHERE assignments.user_id = 31
```

have a look at this

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp